# Why could the TLS handshake fail?

Tags: openvpn

My OpenVPN client (Windows 10) is in a corporate LAN and connects to a server on Internet (Ubuntu). The setup used to work but stopped some time ago (see below for the small infrastructure change, the configuration of either the server or client did not change).

In the logs below

- the OpenVPN server address is `SERVERIP`
- when leaving the corporate LAN, the source address is `CORPORATEIP` (it is SNATed from the internal IP of the client)

When attempting to connect from the client, I get the following log:

```
Sun May 29 10:55:07 2016 OpenVPN 2.3.11 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on May 10 2016
Sun May 29 10:55:07 2016 Windows version 6.2 (Windows 8 or greater) 64bit
Sun May 29 10:55:07 2016 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016, LZO 2.09
Sun May 29 10:55:07 2016 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sun May 29 10:55:07 2016 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Sun May 29 10:55:08 2016 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25340
Sun May 29 10:55:08 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Sun May 29 10:55:08 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Sun May 29 10:55:08 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Sun May 29 10:55:08 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Sun May 29 10:55:08 2016 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'proxy NONE  '
Sun May 29 10:55:09 2016 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
Sun May 29 10:55:09 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1464512109,RESOLVE,,,
Sun May 29 10:55:09 2016 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sun May 29 10:55:09 2016 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]SERVERIP:1194
Sun May 29 10:55:09 2016 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1464512109,WAIT,,,
```

On the server side this corresponds to

```
May 29 10:55:09 srv ovpn-server[732]: CORPORATEIP:15057 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]CORPORATEIP:15057, sid=38d5a524 b40f69aa
May 29 10:56:09 srv ovpn-server[732]: CORPORATEIP:15057 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
May 29 10:56:09 srv ovpn-server[732]: CORPORATEIP:15057 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
May 29 10:56:09 srv ovpn-server[732]: CORPORATEIP:15057 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
May 29 10:56:12 srv ovpn-server[732]: CORPORATEIP:15082 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]CORPORATEIP:15082, sid=36d1f0e9 9cdc88ec
```

So the client does reach the server, attempts a connection and then `TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds` happens.

The [OpenVPN FAQ](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/faq/79-client/253-tls-error-tls-key-negotiation-failed-to-occur-within-60-seconds-check-your-network-connectivity.html) mentions this error and suggests that the traffic may be firewalled (on the server or on the client). This is not the case since the client reaches the server (so `udp/1154` traffic is open on the firewalls).

The setup used to work, the only change I can think of was a change on the server side: it used to be in a LAN, with `udp/1154` forwarded to it, it is now in a DMZ (where it manages the DNATs itself via iptables/shorewall, if needed). Since the packets from the client do reach the server, I do not think this is the reason.

Before digging further, I would like to push firewalling issues aside:

- My understanding from the above is that the client -> server connection works.
- Traffic from the OpenVPN server to the world is open (I can ping `CORPORATEIP` for instance, `UDP` and `TCP` are also open)

**Is my assumption above about firewalling not being the issue correct?**

(Since I wanted t make sure that the return path is not obstructed, I put a small HTTP server on the server and connected to it from the corporate LAN, the connection goes through (the same path))

---

```
# server configuration
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun0
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
dh /etc/openvpn/dh2048.pem
server 10.10.13.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
duplicate-cn
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

---

```
# client configuration
route-nopull
route 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.10.11.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.10.12.0 255.255.255.0
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote SERVER_IP 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEgDCCA2igAwIBAgIJ...
(...)
b4yiCAmaA8p5JRYqYBiT...
p20oZw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
Certificate:
(...)
         8f:d4:9d:d0
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE3DCCA8SgAwIBAgIBA...
(...)
eGOJMoV4vXQ31DZmEl33l...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvwIBADANBgkqhkiG9...
(...)
APOSuHJ4aXJocgOK3jGoK...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
```

---

Comment: Can you post your (redacted) full client and server configs?  I'm suspecting MTU-related issues.  Also, you might want to run tcpdump (or wireshark) to see what packets are coming forth and back.

Comment: I added the configuration files - they have not changed between the moment OpenVPN worked and now. I will run a tcpdump on both sides too.

Comment: Hm, no mtu-related options in there.  That kills my MTU theory (at least as far is I understand these issues).  tcpdump might however show you where the return packets get dropped (if they are sent out at all).

Comment: From my experience four issues can have place: 1st time sync (certificate is not valid yet), 2nd firewall blocking outbound traffic, 3rd routing issue, return traffic is (p)NAT-ed incorrectly using wrong address, 4th - CRL rejection, the certificate has been revoked. It seems like 3rd one, can you show us your server's routing table and client routing table before and after you start OpenVPN?

Comment: 5th, according to this: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/IOSinline , your <cert> inline option in client config file is wrong. It seems to need PEM format.

Comment: @MichalSokolowski: I will get the routing tables. About your 5th: this configuration worked with exactly the same configuration files on both sides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: The problem ended up being at the outbound firewall.**

This is a firewall with a transparent proxy which filters, among others, "applications" (how this is done is proprietary - this is a BlueCoat device). I am authorized to use VPNs (this includes OpenVPN) and the daemon handling the authorization crashed during the week-end - effectively discarding my packets.

This is a localized problem and I considered deleting the question but there is a weird behavior which may help someone who faces a similar problem: only some of the OpenVPN packets are tagged as "VPN" by the BlueCoat - so the initial connection was going through (namely `CLIENT_HARD_RESET`) but other packets (`SERVER_HARD_RESET` to start with) were blocked.

It would have been much easier to troubleshoot if everything was blocked, what was misleading was the partially dropped traffic.